# Variable scope with function

Tags: python, scope

Trying to understand variable scope with a function call.

Code to discuss.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Function to add a column with random stuff to a dataframe 
def Add_a_column(df):
    df['Col2']= np.sign(np.random.randn(len(df)))
    return df

# Create a dataframe with random stuff
df_full = pd.DataFrame(data=np.sign(np.random.randn(5)), columns=['Col1'])

df_another = Add_a_column(df_full)
```

- df_full is global. Correct?
- df_another is global.  Correct?
- df is local to Add_a_column.  Correct?

When I execute the code, the column get's added to df_full

```
In[8]: df_full
Out[8]: 
   Col1  Col2
0  -1.0  -1.0
1   1.0  -1.0
2  -1.0   1.0
3   1.0   1.0
4   1.0   1.0
```

How do I avoid df_full being modified by the function?

Comment: The *name* `df` is local to the function, but `df` and `df_full` refer to the *same* object.

Comment: sounds like you want to clone df_full in the function, manipulate the new object, and then send that back.

Comment: Expanding a bit what @DanielRoseman said, and without knowing anything about Pandas, I imagine you need to copy the `df_full` before passing it to the `Add_a_column` function? (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html ) and read why this happens here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/289011

Comment: @BorrajaX or clone in the function. Im not sure what his end goal is.

Comment: @BorrajaX You are correct but in pandas this might actually be a bit of a shock for the OP since a _lot_ of operations require `inplace=True` to actually take effect in such a way, so I can see where their confusion comes from :)

Comment: The OP should read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1):

`df_full`'s reference is passed into the function. So `df` and `df_full` are the same object, meaning they both get modified when one is modified.

You need to change your function to:

```
def Add_a_column(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['Col2']= np.sign(np.random.randn(len(df)))
    return df
```

Alternatively, you could call the function with a copied function like `Add_a_column(df.copy())`

Answer (score 0):

> - df_full is global. Correct?
> - df_another is global.  Correct?
> - df is local to Add_a_column.  Correct?

It sounds like you understand scope just fine. Each variable had the scope you describe.

The piece you are missing is that `df_full` and `df` refer too the same object. When you make changes to that object with one variable, the changes are visible when you access that object with the other variable.